# LEFT side navigation header

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have HTML template with Fixed top menu header

Now I need to change that top menu header to LEFT side menu header

Is there any simple step available??

```
********************************
________________________________
| H |           My             |
| E |       Scroll_able        |
| A |          Page            |
| D            Here            |
| E |                          |
| R |                          |
!______________________________!

********************************
```

Comment: Could we have your current code please?

Comment: Something like this? http://getbootstrap.com/examples/dashboard/

Comment: @PraveenKumar  Illa mama already ethuna iruntha use pannikama la... recyclability...

Comment: @GaneshRahul Check my answer then. `:)`

Comment: @GaneshRahul Illa machaa, you cud have posted some basic code na? Idhu thappu da SO porutha verikkum!

Comment: @PraveenKumar  I stuck with that da....Tho... paru kelea irukkurathum try panni pathen ana alignment problem varuthu machi

Comment: @GaneshRahul Share your full code in http://jsbin.com da...

Comment: @PraveenKumar https://shapebootstrap.net/item/1524983-spirit8-free-bootstrap-html-template.................... Ithu than macha template

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97123/discussion-between-ganesh-rahul-and-praveen-kumar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
left: 0;
top: auto;
height: 100%;
width: 100px; /* Or whatever here */
```

**Example**

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; text-decoration: none;}
section {position: relative; padding-left: 150px;}
section aside {position: fixed; left: 0; padding: 15px; background-color: #666; color: #fff; height: 100%;}
section aside a {color: inherit; display: block; padding: 5px;}
section aside a:hover {background-color: #fff; color: #000;}
```

```html
<section>
  <aside>
    <h3>Left Sidebar</h3>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Item 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </aside>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet natus dolorum tempora consequatur, magni omnis maxime perferendis similique, dolor eius sapiente optio, officia aliquam necessitatibus, possimus temporibus libero ducimus! Maiores!</p>
  <p>Perferendis quae sint, amet voluptates assumenda est at sapiente! Atque, eligendi explicabo id rerum eos ipsa natus est, reiciendis labore in mollitia ad delectus. Asperiores nihil cum sint explicabo praesentium!</p>
  <p>Ipsa autem harum eum libero, fugiat, commodi dicta, expedita aspernatur minus, delectus eligendi incidunt natus minima mollitia enim. Dicta earum quo, obcaecati voluptate veniam error dignissimos expedita porro reprehenderit architecto?</p>
  <p>Quo dolorum non blanditiis debitis aspernatur earum nulla ut sit unde doloribus? Cumque sed debitis error dolor earum non optio aut nemo, nobis fuga nisi aspernatur quidem dicta ab suscipit.</p>
  <p>Saepe qui voluptates eum iure repellat, eos ut ipsam debitis excepturi, consequuntur tenetur? Corporis quam molestiae doloremque qui quo, rem sint recusandae, molestias culpa iusto reiciendis mollitia alias ipsum veniam.</p>
</section>
```